# How to define a graph, based on automatically changing data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I have an Excel sheet (called `Sheet1`), where I regularly add some data. By pushing a button, a summary of that data gets written on a next page (called `Evolution`), and on that next page, there's also a graph, and that graph seems to be wrong in the sense that it does not update: the graph has been set as having its "Chart data range" like `=Evolution!$B$2:$F$10`, but when a row gets added to this range, it does not automatically update to `=Evolution!$B$2:$F$11`.

There's one thing which might be helpful: I already have defined a name `Evolution_Total_Count` (in cell A3), which calculates the amount of rows I need for the graph, but here's where the fun starts: I'm thinking of a chart data range like this:

```
=Offset(Evolution!B2:B2;Evolution_Total_Count;5)
```

- The idea is:

  - Start with cell B2
  - The number of rows to take can be found in the name `Evolution_Total_Count`
  - The number of columns equals 5 (there are five columns indeed)
- The reality is:

  - This is not the correct way to use the `Offset` worksheet function. (But what is the right way and how can I test this, how can I test a formula, returning a range?)
  - When I enter the name `Evolution_Total_Count` in the `Offset` worksheet function, Excel is not using the value (currently being 9), but the cell reference, where that name is defined (A3).

Does anybody know how I can define the chart data range of my chart, preferebly using the name `Evolution_Total_Count`? (I prefer not to create a name for the whole table.)

For clarity purposes, hereby a sample of what my `Evolution` worksheet looks like:

```
   |          A           B              C            D             E              F
---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |
2  |  Amount of         Date    Still open   Still open  First answer  Second answer
   |    entries                   (amount)      average       average        average
3  |          9    20/07/2018            7  12,14285714   8,368421053    8,863636364
4  |               23/07/2018            8       13,625          7,95    8,869565217
5  |               26/07/2018           11  17,63636364   7,043478261    7,785714286
6  |               06/08/2018           10         22,5   6,272727273    7,444444444
7  |               09/08/2018           10         24,8   5,621621622           6,95
8  |               10/08/2018           10         18,9   5,413043478           6,25
9  |               11/09/2018           13  30,38461538   4,677419355              7
10 |               17/09/2018           11  37,54545455   5,117647059    7,109589041
11 |               26/09/2018           10         27,5   4,901234568    6,823529412
```

Comment: You say "whole table", but is this in an Excel table format?  A defined table would probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your data as a table and base your graph off of that.  Your `Chart Data Range` would still be a data range instead of the table name and it would include the header, so that if row 1 was your header row your range would be:

`=Evolution!$B$1:$F$10`

When you add a row, the range will adjust to

`=Evolution!$B$1:$F$11`