# Dynamically extended chart, horizontal data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

What im asking is I believe called defined names. I have basic understanding to Excel usage and I love the software. Given in I have data that looks like this:

```
Date     | Value A | Value B | Value C
1.1.2019 | 20      | 20      | 20 
2.1.2019 | 22      | 21      | 20
3.1.2019 | 23      | 25      | 26
```

Im looking to create line graph that updates automatically when you enter new data rows - one graph for each value. I already tried using OFFSET and COUNTA functions with no luck. Any tips?

Comment: Try looking into PivotCharts

Comment: See if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1361797/how-to-define-a-graph-based-on-automatically-changing-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a graph, based on automatically changing data?](https://superuser.com/questions/1361797/how-to-define-a-graph-based-on-automatically-changing-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @ReyJuna, seems that there are way easier solutions than OFFSET&COUNTA.

- Turn the data structure to formatted table
- Base the line graph on the formatted table
- Chart data range will automatically change when the formatted table is expanded
- Since formatted data table and chart data range is modified, the line graph is also drawn again

(However, note that removing rows from data does not trigger correct line graph ranges)